# Why adding a new column to an existing table destroyed the performance of a query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 11, and I have the following two tables:
[image: Visualization of the two tables]
As you can see, the `registration` table has a primary key composed of 3 varchar columns (I know), and the `task` table has a foreign key to the `registration` table. Each of these tables has around 4-6 million records. I also have the following query (generated by JPA) that is executed semi-regularly:

```sql
select registrati0_.product_service_instance_id as product_6_4_1_, registrati0_.service_id as service_1_4_1_, registrati0_.version_id as version_2_4_1_, registrati0_.created as created3_4_1_, registrati0_.dependencies as dependen4_4_1_, registrati0_.is_manually_created as is_manua5_4_1_, tasks1_.registration_product_service_instance_id as registra8_6_3_, tasks1_.registration_service_id as registra9_6_3_, tasks1_.registration_version_id as registr10_6_3_, tasks1_.name as name1_6_3_, tasks1_.name as name1_6_0_, tasks1_.registration_product_service_instance_id as registra8_6_0_, tasks1_.registration_service_id as registra9_6_0_, tasks1_.registration_version_id as registr10_6_0_, tasks1_.content_etag as content_2_6_0_, tasks1_.created as created3_6_0_, tasks1_.depends_on as depends_4_6_0_, tasks1_.phases as phases5_6_0_, tasks1_.retry_count as retry_co6_6_0_ from registration registrati0_ left outer join task tasks1_ on registrati0_.product_service_instance_id=tasks1_.registration_product_service_instance_id and registrati0_.service_id=tasks1_.registration_service_id and registrati0_.version_id=tasks1_.registration_version_id where registrati0_.product_service_instance_id=$1 and registrati0_.service_id=$2 and registrati0_.version_id=$3;
```

It's kind of hard to read, so I'll try to simplify it a bit:

```sql
SELECT registration.*, task.*
FROM registration
LEFT OUTER JOIN task ON registration.product_service_instance_id=task.registration_product_service_instance_id
  AND registration.service_id=task.registration_service_id
  AND registration.version_id=task.registration_version_id
WHERE registration.product_service_instance_id=$1
  AND registration.service_id=$2
  AND registration.version_id=$3
```

(Sorry about the crap formatting!)

This query used to have a decent performance (<4 seconds). However, after adding the `created` column to the `task` table, its execution time jumped up to >4 minutes even though I am not using the new column in the `WHERE` clause! Before moving on further, here's how I added the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE task
ADD COLUMN created TIMESTAMP; -- Nullable
UPDATE task SET created=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE created IS NULL;
```

From what I read online, updating a row in PostgreSQL is equal to `INSERT` + `DELETE`, so my update probably resulted in a complete table re-write. Can anyone confirm this, by the way? However, even if that's true, **why did the query suddenly become so slow?**

I know about the PostgreSQL [issue with adding a new column with a default value](https://www.depesz.com/2018/04/04/waiting-for-postgresql-11-fast-alter-table-add-column-with-a-non-null-default/), but that only affects the performance of the update query itself - not of consecutive selects. Maybe there was some cache on PostgreSQL-side (a temporary index or something) that got invalidated when I added the new column?

The only thing that brought the query's execution time back to reasonable values was adding a new index to the task table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS idx_task_registration_ids ON task (registration_product_service_instance_id, registration_service_id, registration_version_id)
```

It made the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` extremely fast.

Can anyone explain what happened so that I can avoid such issues in the future?

Comment: can anyone look into the problem pls- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252276/sql-calculate-day-1-retention-rate-from-user-registration-table-and-event-log/73613016#73613016

Answer (score 2):

Please check the bloat on the table. This update would have created a lot of dirty records which can be cleared using the VACUUM operation.
Check query for bloat here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Sonia! Unfortunately, several auto vacuum operations have passed since I added the column, and I'm not sure whether the output I got from running the query is still relevant. It says that the `tbloat` of the index I created is `39.8` (wasted bytes - 4885274624). The `tbloat` of the primary key on the task table is also `39.8`, but it also has a significant amount of `wastedibytes`. I'm not sure what's the difference between the two. Can you explain in a few lines? Also, do you believe that these levels of table bloat could lead to such large performance degradations?